# Маска (UI) Unity для обучения в мобильной игре

Tags: c#, unity3d, ui

**Необходимо сделать что-то подобное**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но так, чтобы была основная панель (черный фон) на весь экран, а передвигать именно блок на которой должна быть маска (Train_1 на приведенном фото ниже).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать с маской на основном фоне (черном, в данном случае) я понимаю, но как сделать так, чтобы нужно было передвигать только блок внутри основного, причем чтобы сам блок внутри мог вырезать основной я не понимаю.

Нашел небольшой скрипт в интернете, но он аналогично вешается на основной объект, а не дочерний:

```
public class CutoutMask_UI : Image
{
    public override Material materialForRendering
    {
        get
        {
            Material material = new Material(base.materialForRendering);
            material.SetInt("_StencilComp", (int)CompareFunction.NotEqual);
            return material;
        }
    }
}
```

Сие решение мне необходимо для того, чтобы в дальнейшем было проще реализовывать обучение для игрока (анимации, изменение размеров дочернего объекта и прочего).

Comment: 4 `Image`, блокирующие все импуты кроме квадратной дырки, которую они вместе образуют.

Comment: @Yaroslav не самый лучший вариант

Comment: Блокировать импуты за пределами подсвеченной зоны, тебе все равно придется, а по каким таким критерия `не самый лучший`, одному тебе понятно. Обычно обсуждая варианты решения, люди отталкиваются от решаемой проблемы/задачи, что бы был фундамент под ногами.

Comment: А чем не подходит вариант Ярослава? Это типичное решение, и довольное логичное

Comment: @AlemkhanUtepkaliev что подразумевается под инпутами?